# MVVMCross How to implement a ContentDialog

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, dialog, mvvmcross

I have a [small example github repo](https://github.com/cj-prog/MvvmCrossContentDialog) in which I like to **open a custom ContentDialog** (SpeechDialog) after a button is clicked, using the **MVVMCross** framework.

If I implement a ContentDialog with MVVM **without a framework**, the MainView will look like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainView : Page
{
    public MainView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ISpeechDialogService dialog = new SpeechDialogService();
        MainViewModel= new MainViewModel(dialog);
    }
    public MainViewModel MainViewModel{ get; set; }
}
```

But in **MVVMCross** I have an attributed MainView and I don't know how to pass the ContentDialog:

```
[MvxViewFor(typeof(MainViewModel))]
public sealed partial class MainView : MvxWindowsPage
{
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Some code for a better understanding:**

SpeechDialogService.cs:

```
public class SpeechDialogService : ISpeechDialogService
{
    public async Task ShowAsync()
    {
        var contentDialog = new Speech();
        await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

}

[directlink to the Speech.xaml](https://github.com/cj-prog/MvvmCrossContentDialog/blob/master/MvvmCrossContentDialog.UWP/Views/Speech.xaml)

**TL;DR**

Is my approach right? If yes, **how can I pass a ContentDialog** to the MainViewModel? If not, **how to implement a ContentDialog with MVVMCross**?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ViewModelLocator here and use MVVM pattern, regardless of the framework. See sample implementation.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public MainPageViewModel MainPageViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            ISpeechDialogService dialogService = new SpeechDialogService();
            MainPageViewModel vm = new MainPageViewModel(dialogService);
            return vm;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, you can use Autofac to resolve your ViewModels' dependecies, also make the service singleton https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/index.html

Then in your App.xaml, add a resource for locator:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <services:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Then in your page (preferably not in code behind) you should assign your DataContext like so:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
    DataContext="{Binding MainPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

</Page>
```

Then your ViewModel should look like:

```
using App1.Services;

namespace App1.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        private readonly ISpeechDialogService _speechDialogService;
        public MainPageViewModel(ISpeechDialogService speechDialogService)
        {
            _speechDialogService = speechDialogService;
        }
    }
}
```

Your dialog service look like:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App1.Services
{
    public class SpeechDialogService : ISpeechDialogService
    {
        public async Task ShowAsync()
        {
            var contentDialog = new Speech();
            await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.